# Add List<Model> to List inside List<Model>

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, dictionary, dart

I have three models in my project, `LibraryModel`, `LibraryContentsModel`, and `BooksModel`.

`LibraryModel`: a model for local JSON file.

`BooksModel`: a model for SQLite database.

`LibraryContentsModel`: a model I created for search and filter into SQLite database.

---

`LibraryModel`:

```
class LibraryModel {
    final String? title;
    final String? fullTitle;
    final String? subject;
    final int? id;
    final int? count;
    final String? image;
    final String? dbName;
    final String? part;
    bool? isSelected;
  LibraryModel({
    this.title,
    this.fullTitle,
    this.subject,
    this.id,
    this.count,
    this.image,
    this.dbName,
    this.part,
    this.isSelected,
  });
}
```

`BooksModel`:

```
class BooksModel {
  final int? id;
  final String? pageTitle;
  final String? pageText;
  final String? footTitle;
  BooksModel({
    this.id,
    this.pageTitle,
    this.pageText,
    this.footTitle,
  });
}
```

`LibraryContentsModel`:

```
class LibraryContentsModel {
  int? id;
  String? title;
  String? part;
  String? dbName;
  List<BooksModel>? booksList;
  LibraryContentsModel({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.part,
    this.dbName,
    this.booksList,
  });
}
```

**Problem:**

I need to insert data from SQLite Database into the `booksList` parameter in `LibraryContetnsModel` which is already defined named of table SQLite in `LibraryModel`, each table contains data in order.

**Fetch Code:**

```
Future loadLibrary() async {
  setState(() => isLoad = true);
  try {
    libraryList.addAll(await LibraryService.instance.getLibrary());
    for (var item in libraryList) {
      booksList
          .addAll(await DatabaseService.instance.getBooks(item.dbName ?? ""));
      libraryContentsList.add(
        LibraryContentsModel(
          id: item.id,
          title: item.title,
          part: item.part,
          dbName: item.dbName,
          // booksList: [booksList].expand((element) => element).toList(), <-- When I run this line get me exception
        ),
      );
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
  setState(() => isLoad = false);
}
```

### Edit

I need Like this example:

```
LibraryModel:
  id: 1
  title: "Clean Code"
  part: "2nd Edition"
  dbName: "clean_code"
...

BooksModel:
  id: 115
  pageTitle: "Test Automation Pyramid"
  pageText: "Professional developers employ the discipline of Test Driven Development...."
  footTitle: "[COHN09] pp.311-312"

LibraryContentsModel:
  id: LibraryModel.id = 1
  title: LibraryModel.title = "Clean Code"
  part: LibraryModel.part = "2nd Edition"
  dbName: LibraryModel.dbName = "clean_code"
  booksList: BooksModel(
  id: 115
  pageTitle: "Test Automation Pyramid"
  pageText: "Professional developers employ the discipline of Test Driven Development...."
  footTitle: "[COHN09] pp.311-312"
)
```

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't use just

```
LibraryContentsModel(
  ...
  bookList: booklist, // already fetched
),
```